# How to fix decimal places of a Uint128 variable in rust

Tags: rust, decimal, rust-cargo

Rust newbie here. I am trying to calculate amount deducted from a value based on rate and decimal places in rate.

Without the decimal places, suppose if I want to deduct 2% amount from original (where 2 is the rate), this is how I am accomplishing it:

```
 let original = token_value[0].amount;
 token_value[0].amount = original * Decimal::percent(98);
```

What if I want to also define the decimal places in rate and then make the deduction, how will I accomplish that? The crates that I used are **cosmwasm_std::{Decimal,Uint128}**

Comment: What crate are you using?

Comment: Decimal and Uint128 of cosmwasm standard . cosmwasm_std::{Decimal,Uint128}.

Comment: What about [`Decimal::from_ratio`](https://docs.rs/cosmwasm-std/latest/cosmwasm_std/struct.Decimal.html#method.from_ratio)?

Comment: yeah, this can give me what i want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take 2% of original amount as fees

you can do

```
// Here we hardcode the swap fees as 2/100 or 2% of from_amount

fn get_swap_fee(from_amount: Uint128) -> StdResult<Uint128> {
        from_amount
            .checked_mul(Uint128::from(2u128))
            .map_err(StdError::overflow)?
            .checked_div(Uint128::from(100u128))
            .map_err(StdError::divide_by_zero)
    }
```